# Cannot change default data in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

1. I added metadata/data in docker container ( PostgreSQL ). I sow changes in DB, Superset ( dashboards, datasets )
2. I created new images by command: docker commit my_old_image my_new_image_name
3. I pushed it to docker hub.
4. I added new image to my docker-compose.yml file :

```
db:
    env_file: docker/.env
    image: my_new_image_name
    container_name: superset_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_home:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Did not see any changes in default datasets.

Comment: Where's the configuration for these "default datasets"?

Comment: `docker commit` doesn't save database data.  In your example, it's in the `db_home` named volume and not part of the container temporary filesystem, so `commit` doesn't see it.  You should pretty much never run `docker commit` at all: the images it produces can't be recreated, audited, or rebuilt to change the version of the underlying software.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue might be related to the volume binding for your PostgreSQL container in the docker-compose.yml file.

When you use a bind mount (as you're doing with the volumes directive in the docker-compose.yml file), Docker mounts the specified directory from the host system into the container. In your case, it looks like you're mounting db_home (which is presumably defined elsewhere in your docker-compose.yml as a named volume) to /var/lib/postgresql/data inside the container.

Here's the key point: If there's data in db_home on the host system, that data will effectively "overwrite" whatever data is in the container's /var/lib/postgresql/data directory when the container starts. This means that even if you committed changes to the container's image, the data in the image would be ignored in favor of the data in the db_home volume when you start a new container from that image.

To see the changes in your new image, you have a couple of options:

**Temporary Check:** You can temporarily comment out the volume binding in your docker-compose.yml and then start the container. This will allow the container to use the data that's baked into the image, rather than the data from the bind mount:

```
db:
    ...
    # volumes:
    #   - db_home:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

1. **Permanent Change**: If you want the changes to be permanent in the db_home volume:
   1.1. Backup any important data from your existing db_home volume.
   1.2. Remove the existing db_home volume.
   1.3. Start your container. This will create a new db_home volume containing the data from your new image.
   1.4. Restore any additional data you backed up in step 1.

To remove a volume, you can use the following command (but be very careful, as this will delete data):

```
docker volume rm db_home
```

Always remember to backup your data before making any changes to ensure you don't lose any important information.

Comment: Thanks for info. But I found that when I commit copy of my container and run it I see data. But after pushing it on docker hub and then starting docker compose - I do not see any data left in my container.